# How to debug a regex that is not matching in my automation tool?

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression to match a new email notification in an automation tool on my phone.  What I'm matching against is:

```
Urgent Ticket Notification (12345 - Open)
```

The only variation will be in the number (which will not always be 5 digits), and the text will otherwise be the same. I only want a match the first time the email is sent (not if someone forwards it, which will prepend a "FW:". What I've come up with is:

```
^Urgent\sTicket\sNotification\s\(\d+\s-\sOpen\)
```

I tested the expression successfully at http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html, but I have not successfully matched beyond "Urgent Ticket Notification" in my automation tool. Is there a better way to write this?

Edit: Thank you all for your responses - To answer your questions,

Acceptable matches are
    Urgent Ticket Notification (XXXX - Open)
Where XXXX = any integer. 
I don't want to match 
FW: Urgent Ticket Notification (XXXX - Open) (if someone forwards me the email for example)

I am using a tool called Automagic (similar to Tasker). Basically, what I am trying to do is have my phone alert me when emails with certain subjects come in (an alert different from the standard "new mail" notification).

As far as what the issue is, I also get a "Fully matches string" when I test it, but in the tool, it isn't triggering. I will do as @halfer suggested and try bit by bit.

Comment: I pasted the string and regex, and got *Fully matches the source string!* What is your issue?

Comment: Your regex is very specific!, when you are using this regex you are telling that from start of string it is as same as `"Urgent Ticket Notification ("` + some digits + `" - Open)"`, and also instead of space only you are accepting tab or line-feeds, We can't suggest a better way without knowing about all you acceptable combinations -HTH ;).

Comment: What tool are you using? Maybe it uses a different flavour of regex. A good way to debug is to try pieces, in order to see where it fails - does it match on `^Urgent` for example? If so, add another piece, etc.

Comment: You can use this website: https://regex101.com/